# How to name the element of the list in r?

Tags: r

Suppose I have this list:

```
my_variable <- list()
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
y <- c(4,5,7,3)
for ( i in 1:4){
my_variable[[i]] <- x[i]*y[i]+2
}
```

Then I will get this:

```
  [[1]]
[1] 6

[[2]]
[1] 12

[[3]]
[1] 23

[[4]]
[1] 14
```

How to name the element of the output, like this:

```
 > my_variable
    First_result
[1] 6

    Second_result
[1] 12
```

and so on.

Comment: `names(my_variable) <- [vector of names you want to assign]`

Comment: You can use `names(my_variable) <- c(some stuff)` or replace `c(some stuff)` with a clever use of `paste` like `paste("result", 1:4, sep="_")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with the `paste0` and `names`

```
# So first you define vector of names:
names1 <- c("First","Second","Third","Fourth")
# And second you paste them to your list
names(my_variable) <- paste0(names1,"_result",  sep = "")

#And the output
$First_result
[1]  6 12 23 14

$Second_result
[1]  6 12 23 14

$Third_result
[1]  6 12 23 14

$Fourth_result
[1]  6 12 23 14
```