# How to return an element from the function that return a list in r?

Tags: r

I built my own function like this:

```
library(VineCopula)

Matrix <- c(5, 2, 3, 1, 4,
            0, 2, 3, 4, 1,
            0, 0, 3, 4, 1,
            0, 0, 0, 4, 1,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
Matrix <- matrix(Matrix, 5, 5)
family <-par <- par2 <-  list()
for(i in 1:3){
# define R-vine pair-copula family matrix
family[[i]] <- c(0, 1, 3, 4, 4,
            0, 0, 3, 4, 1,
            0, 0, 0, 4, 1,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 3,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
family[[i]] <- matrix(family[[i]], 5, 5)
# define R-vine pair-copula parameter matrix
par[[i]] <- c(0, 0.2, 0.9, 1.5, 3.9,
         0, 0, 1.1, 1.6, 0.9,
         0, 0, 0, 1.9, 0.5,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 4.8,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
par[[i]] <- matrix(par[[i]], 5, 5)
# define second R-vine pair-copula parameter matrix
par2[[i]] <- matrix(0, 5, 5)
}
my_func <- function(Matrix, family, par, par2){
     x <- list()
     for(i in 1:3){
          x[[i]] <- RVineMatrix(Matrix = Matrix,family=family[[i]],par=par[[i]],par2 = par2[[i]])
     }
     x
}
```

This will return me a list. How can I then extract specific element from my function. For example, how I can get `my_func$Matrix` or `my_func$par[1]`
Note: `family <– par <– par2 <– list()`. I also tried `return(x[i]$family[i])` and return `NULL`.

To run the function:

```
y <- my_func(Matrix = Matrix,family = family,par = par,par2 = par2)

> y$Matrix
NULL
```

Comment: Here is a good example of how you can rename your output.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44892153/how-to-name-the-element-of-the-list-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to assign the outcome of that function to something. For example:

```
y <- my_func(Matrix = ... , family = ..., par = ..., par2 = ...)
```

where `...` above are the values of your arguments. Based on your `my_func` definition, the end result is an unnamed list so to access its elements you use:

```
y[[1]]
y[[2]]
y[[3]]
```

or just `y` to access all elements.

Comment: Really!! is that simple :( Thank you so much.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with some data (see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @constantions there is a function inside my function.

Comment: I've edited the answer accordingly. You can accept it if it solves your problem.

Comment: You can use `names(y) <- c("A", "B", "C")` or something more suitable and you can access them as: `y$A` etc.

Comment: please add the names to your answer to be very usefull for other.

Comment: I believe it would be better if the list elements are named within your function `my_func`. That way anytime you use that function, the elements will already be named.

Answer (score 2):

Your function's return value is a `list`of class `RVineMatrix` with an element named `Matrix`. See the help page `?RVineMatrix`, section `Value`. So you need `y[[1]]$Matrix`.

```
y <- my_func(Matrix, family, par, par2)
class(y)
[1] "list"
class(y[[1]])
[1] "RVineMatrix"

y[[1]]$Matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    5    0    0    0    0
[2,]    2    2    0    0    0
[3,]    3    3    3    0    0
[4,]    1    4    4    4    0
[5,]    4    1    1    1    1
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you.